# C#, User Control, Events - User Control's Control Event Overriding?

Tags: c#, events, button, user-controls, event-handling

In my C# program, I have a Custom Control with a label and a button. How can I setup my control so that when a user clicks the button it overrides the Custom Control's Click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call the control's OnClick() method:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.OnClick(e);
    }
```

Which fires the control's Click event.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly! I tried somthing similar to this and it did not work, in the end though it was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
public new event EventHandler Click {
  add { button1.Click += value; }
  remove { button1.Click -= value; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This also worked liked a charm! I havn't used C#/VB/C++ Since Visual Studio 6.0 so I am still learning simple things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full article which explain you how you can achieve it : [**Exposing Custom event from custom control**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2012/01/exposing-custom-event-from-custom.html)

Following is step for the drodown used in user control and exposing event you need to do same for you button , you will get more idea after reading above link

**Step 1 : Register event in user control cs file**

```
public event EventHandler DrpChange;
```

**Step 2 : Virtual function to handle raised event in usercontrol cs file**

```
public virtual void OnDropDownChange()
    {
        if (DrpChange != null)
        {
            this.DrpChange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

**Step 3 : Register on Change Event of dropdown in ASCX.CS file**

```
protected void ddlDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnDropDownChange();
    }
```

**Step 4 : Use User control on page and utilize expose custom event .Aspx page**

```
<uc1:commondropdowncontrol autopostback="true" drpchange="usrDrp_DrpChange" id="usrDrp" labletext="Country" runat="server">
    </uc1:commondropdowncontrol></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will check out that article along with the rest of your nice site.